# How can I combine Countuniqueifs on Google Sheet

Tags: google-sheets, google-sheets-formula, formula

I have a sample table with three columns: Validity, Branch, Brand

| Validity | Branch | Brand |
| --- | --- | --- |
| In-Store Only | Espresso Hub - New York | Espresso Hub |
| Delivery Only | Espresso Hub - Los Angeles | Espresso Hub |
| In-Store & Delivery | Espresso Hub - Denver | Espresso Hub |
| Delivery Only | Panini House - Chicago | Panini House |
| In-Store Only | Panini House - Austin | Panini House |
| In-Store Only | Green Life Cafe - Santa Ana | Green Life |
| In-Store & Delivery | Garden Cafe - Orlando | Garden Cafe |
| Delivery Only | Crunchy Munchies - Aurora | Crunchy Munchies |

I am using the formula below to get the unique count of brands based on validity.

```
=Countuniqueifs(C2:C11, A2:A11, "In-Store Only") and  

=Countuniqueifs(C2:C11, A2:A11, "Delivery Only") and 

=Countuniqueifs(C2:C11, A2:A11, "In-Store & Delivery")
```

The tagging of validity is on branch level. However I need to combine the formula in such a way that it will give me the unique count of brand based on 2 tags. For example, I want the unique number of brands with both *"In-Store"* and *"In-store & Delivery"*.

Then how can I also count it negatively. For example, I need to know the count of brand that is tagged for delivery only, in such  way that any brand with a branch that has in-store will not be counted. For example, Espresso Hub will not be counted because it has branches with an in-store and in-store & delivery tags. So in this case, Crunchy Munchies will be the only brand counted since all it's branches are tagged as delivery only.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

try:

```
=COUNTUNIQUEIFS(C2:C11, A2:A11, REGEXMATCH(A2:A11, "In-Store & Delivery|In-Store Only"))
```